# Round number with NumPy to the nearest thousand, but downward only

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

I am looking for the equivalent of `np.round(234_567, -3)`, which would yield `Out[1]: 235000`. However, I want to round downward only. My desired output is: `Out[1]: 234000`.

```py
import numpy as np

number = 234_567  # find a way to round this downward to 234_000
```

Comment: What should `-234_567` round to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`round` rounds to nearest even; to round down, use `floor` instead. However, since it doesn't have the `decimals` parameter, you need to do that bit yourself:

```
np.floor(234_567 / 1_000) * 1_000
```

or, equivalently

```
np.floor(234_567 / 10 ** 3) * 10 ** 3
```

Comment: If flooring behavior is desired, `//` may be a better option than `/`-and-floor. If rounding toward zero is desired, that's [`numpy.fix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fix.html) rather than `floor`. (I don't know where the name comes from.)

Comment: @user2357112: Re: `//`, true: I was stuck on thinking about `numpy` functions. But this is also more generic, in a way, as it is easy to replace `floor` with `ceil` or `fix` if another behaviour is required which is not as obvious with `//`.